# How to prove that $ x_n $ converges when $ 2x_{n+1}+x_n $ converges by using Stolz–Cesàro theorem?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have already know that by using standard method, we can get that $ x_n $ converges when $ 2x_{n+1}+x_n $ converges. However my teacher said we can use the Stolz–Cesàro theorem to prove this statement. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: What is Stolz theorem?

Comment: It is Stolz–Cesàro.

Comment: Maybe writing $x_n = x_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_i)$ could help?

Comment: I know the Cesaro-Stoltz theorem is applied to sequences of type $x_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ where $b_n$ is incriesing: if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=l$,  then and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=l$. The reciproc is not true in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ c_n=2x_{n+1}+x_n\rightarrow\ell\ $ as $ n\rightarrow\infty\ $, then
\begin{align}
\frac{2^{n+1}x_{n+1}-2^{n-1}x_{n-1}}{2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}}&=\frac{2^n\big(2x_{n+1}+x_{n}\big)-2^{n-1}\big(2x_{n}+x_{n-1}\big)}{2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{2^nc_{n}-2^{n-1}c_{n-1}}{2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{2c_{n}}{3}-\frac{c_{n-1}}{3}\\
&\rightarrow\frac{\ell}{3}\ \ \text{ as }\ n\rightarrow\infty\ .
\end{align}
Let $\ a_r=2^{2r-1}x_{2r-1}\ $, and $\  b_r=2^{2r-1}\ $, then $\ b_r\ $ increases monotonically to $\ \infty\ $, and from above we have
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{r+1}-a_r}{b_{r+1}-b_r}&=\frac{2^{2r+1}x_{2r+1}-2^{2r-1}x_{2r-1}}{2^{2r+1}-2^{2r-1}}\\
&\rightarrow\frac{\ell}{3}\ \ \text{ as }\ r\rightarrow\infty\ .
\end{align}
Therefore, by the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_%E2%88%99/%E2%88%9E_case),
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_r}{b_r}=\frac{\ell}{3}=\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}x_{2r-1}\ .
$$
Now from the identity $\ x_{2r}=\frac{c_{2r-1}-x_{2r-1}}{2}\ $, we obtain
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}x_{2r}=\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{c_{2r-1}-x_{2r-1}}{2}=\frac{\ell}{3}\ .
$$
Thus, since both the even and odd terms of the sequence $\ \big\{x_n\big\}_{n=1}^\infty\ $ converge to the same limit, $\ \frac{\ell}{3}\ $, so does the sequence itself.